# Format nested namespaces in C++ on one line using astyle

Tags: c++, astyle

In my company's coding convention, we format nested namespaces on one line. For example:

```
namespace Foo { namespace Bar {
...
}} // Foo::Bar
```

I am trying to enforce this style using astyle but could not find anything in the documentation at http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html

When I run the following astyle command (ignore the irrelevant options)

```
astyle --style=allman --add-brackets --align-reference=name --align-pointer=name --attach-namespaces --pad-header --pad-oper --unpad-paren -n <filename>
```

I end up with each of the nested namespace on a separate line as shown below:

```
namespace Foo {
namespace Bar {
...
}
}
```

Comment: I was never happy with Astyle. I prefer clang format (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) - there is even a Visual Studio add-in for clang format. Consider switching to clang format.

Comment: I mostly work in vim but don't mind moving to clang-format. Do you know the exact switch for the use case I mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17928

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify `astyle` source code. Find method `ASFormater::isOkToBreakBlock` and insert at the beginning:

```
if (isBraceType(braceType, NAMESPACE_TYPE))
    return false;
```

Make sure that it doesn't break the whole formatting.

P.S. Hope that `astyle` team will hear and will make correct changes with option.